# The origin of binary "image"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, computing

I'm curious why a chunk of binary data is called *image*?

Like disk image, boot image, Linux image, flash image, etc.

In my brain, image is something two-dimensional, but binary data is a one-dimensional octet flow.

Comment: The statement above, "This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link... "  is just ridiculous.  I've been searching on the Internet for just this answer and coming up with nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usage like this of *image* dates from the early years of computing, when "IBM cards" were in common use.  For example, [RFC 678](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc678.txt) (19 December 1974) devotes a paragraph to defining *Card Image*, which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_image) refers to as "an archaic term for an ASCII string, usually 80 bytes in length."  *Card image* is used similarly in pdf [CDC document 60137400](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/cdc/3x00/48bit/60137400_CODAP1_COMPASS_Translator_Jan66.pdf)  pdf (January 1966), but in current usage now often refers to SD [memory-card images](http://www.freelabs.com/~whitis/sd_card/rawimages.html).

The rationale behind such usage is to express the notion of "as-is" or "true" copy.  For example, *binary image* or *executable image* often refer to previously-translated and linked code that could be loaded into memory as-is and executed.
The [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=binary+image%2Cexecutable+image%2Ckernel+image&year_start=1950&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3) below shows growth and decline in usage of several *image* terms.  (Note that much of the usage of *binary image* charted below is for digital representation of pictures, *vs.* usage discussed above.) [image: ngram]

[Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disk+image%2Cboot+image%2CCD+image%2Cexecutable+image&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) also shows that in the last 15 years, usage of *disk image* has become more common than the corresponding *boot, CD,* and *executable* terms.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image) remarks: "A disk image is usually created by creating a complete sector-by-sector copy of the source medium and thereby perfectly replicating the structure and contents of a storage device" (which agrees with the "as-is" or "true-copy" concept mentioned earlier).